# How to express a system of differential equations in a form suitable for numerical methods?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am modeling rocket thrust equations using some of the formulas and derivations on [page 37 & 38 here](http://sargrocket.org/Documents/Estes/TR-10.pdf).

For my Rocket model, I have the following two equations:
$$dv/dt = 383v^2$$
$$dA/dt = 635.14 \tanh(.6033t)$$

I am having a ton of difficulty getting either or both of these equations into an expression that would allows me to use numeric approximation methods such as Euler's Method, Euler's Improved Method, Runge-Kutta, Adam's Bashforth etc, all of which require something along the lines of:

$$dy/dt = y'+yt$$ (both x and y present)

I must be missing something here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations you quote are already in the desired form. Those methods generally want $y'=f(x,y,stuff)$.  Note that the independent variable can appear in any form on the right. In your problem that is $t$. Your suggestion is for $dy/dt=y'=y'+f(x,y)$ but you don't want $y'$ on the right. Both equations separate:  you have $A=\int_0^t 635.14 \tanh (0.6033t)\ dt$, which can be [integrated analytically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20tanh%28x%29)  Similarly, $dv/dt=383v^2, dv/(383v^2)=dt, t=-1/(383v)+C$

Comment: Okay. I understand how to integrate both equations. I just don't understand how I can use them in say Eueler's method or a multistep method, (which is a requirement for a project I am working on).

Comment: Or any other way to use a numeric method to model my rockets flight (altitude). I have found some examples on the web of use of the Runge Kutta method specific to rocket flights, but they do not show the equations they used, just the output.

Comment: In Euler's method, you are doing $y_{n+1}=y_n+y'_n\Delta x$, so you need to supply a function $y'(x,y,stuff)$ and the method takes care of the rest.  In the others it is the same, but they call $y'$ a number of times per step to reduce the errors (if the solution is smooth enough).  If you are writing the integrator instead of using a library routine, it doesn't depend (too much) on the function you are integrating.  Usually the suggestion is to test your routine on $y'=y$ first, as you know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

All numerical methods generalize to systems. You can straight apply Euler's method, Runge-Kutta methods, etc. to this problem. For example, Euler's method would give:

$$v_{n+1} = v_{n} + 383v_{n}^{2} \Delta t $$
$$A_{n+1} = A_{n} + 635.14 \tanh(.6033 t_n) \Delta t $$

where $t_n = n \Delta t $. You just loop through that. Of course, you should use Runge-Kutta methods like MATLAB's ode45, but they're doing something similar to this.